# Merge long/lat points within a bounding box depending on a radius in MySQL

Tags: mysql, haversine

Here is a pic of what I basically want to achieve:

[image]

So as the title says, I want to merge long/lat points which they're radius (of 25Kms for example) touch inside a bounding box of long/lat points.

Here is my very simple DB structure:

```
+-------+-------------+------------+
| id    |        long |        lat |
+-------+-------------+------------+
|     1 |   -90.27137 |   50.00702 |
|     2 |   -92.27137 |   52.00702 |
|     3 |   -87.27137 |   48.00702 |
|     4 |   -91.27137 |   51.00702 |
+-------+-------------+------------+
```

Here is my query so far:

```
set @bottom_lat = -100.27137;
set @bottom_lon = 40.00702;

set @top_lat = -80.27137 ;
set @top_lon = 60.00702 ;
;

SELECT AVG(latitude), AVG(longitude)
FROM destination
WHERE latitude > @bottom_lat AND longitude > @bottom_lon AND latitude < @top_lat AND longitude < @top_lon
```

So my query just merging all points inside an imaginary bounding box without considering radius.

I know that I would prorably have to work with the Haversine formula but I'm crap at maths and MySQL which make things a little bit difficult. Indeed, I could eventually merge points if I had just one radius but each points have its own radius and I'm struggling.

This is for a student project and any help will be much much apreciated.

References:

-My query on SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a42b/2
( contains a SQL Fiddle exemple for the Haversine Formula in comment )

-The Haversine formula in MySQL query: (work for checking all points inside a given radius)

```
SELECT*, ( 6371* acos( cos( radians(
@my_lat) ) * cos( radians( 
destination.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( 
destination.longitude ) - radians(
@my_lon) ) + sin( radians(
@my_lat) ) * sin( radians( 
destination.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM destination
ORDER BY distance limit 1
;
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database  also how you handle the zoom level ?

Comment: Hi, I'm gonna look at it thanks. I'm not sure to understand your question but the zoom level will be handled by variating the radius of each points depending on this zoom.

Answer (score 0):

This operation may be too complicated to execute without the aid of PHP or another programming language. Here's how you could do it in PHP:

```
<?
    $link = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass", "database");

    // Grab all the points from the db and push them into an array
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM data";
    $res = $link->query($sql);
    $arr = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_rows($res); $i++){
        array_push($arr, mysqli_fetch_assoc($res));
    }

    // Cycle through the point array, eliminating those points that "touch" 
    $rad = 1000; //radius in KM
    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); ++$i){
        $lat1 = $arr[$i]['lat'];
        $lon1 = $arr[$i]['long'];
        for($j = 0; $j<count($arr); ++$j){
            if($i != $j && isset($arr[$i]) && isset($arr[$j])){ // do not compare a point to itself
                $lat2 = $arr[$j]['lat'];
                $lon2 = $arr[$j]['long'];
                // get the distance between each pair of points using the haversine formula
                $dist = acos( sin($lat1*pi()/180)*sin($lat2*pi()/180) + cos($lat1*pi()/180)*cos($lat2*pi()/180)*cos($lon2*PI()/180-$lon1*pi()/180) ) * 6371;
                if($dist < $rad){
                    echo "Removing point id:".$arr[$i]['id']."<br>";
                    unset($arr[$i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //display results
    echo "Remaining points:<br>";
    foreach($arr as $val){
        echo "id=".$val['id']."<br>";
    }
?>
```

The output of this code on the data you provided is:

```
    Removing point id:1
    Removing point id:2
    Remaining points:
    id=3
    id=4
```

Note that this just removes the overlapping points, it doesn't do any averaging of positions. You could easily add that though. Hope this helps.