# Average data points within a range of each other?

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis

I have a Pandas data frame with the following columns:

```
lat1    lon1    lat2    lon2
```

`lat` and `lon` variables are latitude and longitude in degrees. Many of the points are very, very close to each other. I want to divide this dataframe up in 'clusters, for example, group all data points that are within 60 feet of each other together. I know I can use `geopy.distance.vincenty` to get the distance between the points. But I'm not sure how I would go about cycling through the dataframe to cluster points based on distance from each other.

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236605/merge-long-lat-points-within-a-bounding-box-depending-on-a-radius-in-mysql). It's a different language but the same problem.

Comment: Do you want to group data points that are within a fixed distance of each other (like 60 feet in your example) or do you want your grouping to be more dynamic? You can take a look at 'Density Based Clustering' algorithms for the latter.

Comment: You can check [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html)

Comment: I was originally going to go with a fixed distance, but I like the idea of a dynamic approach as you both mentioned. Will give it a try, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your task is not well defined.

Consider points a, b, c. Let the distances be: a to b: 40, b to c: 40, a to c 80.

Now if you want to average points within 60, then you would need to average b with both a and c, but not a and c!

You need to be more precise here. Maybe single-link clustering, but maybe you want complete link, or average link, or ward, or DBSCAN, or ...